# Flutter wallet connect authorization and sign in

Tags: flutter, dart, wallet-connect

I went through all these steps according to the documentation but I couldn't establish the connection from my dapp to paraswap:

I try to do the following to connect

Create a connector

```
final web3Wallet = await Web3Wallet.createInstance(
      projectId: '123',
      metadata: const PairingMetadata(
        name: 'Defix3',
        description: 'A wallet that can be requested to sign transactions',
        url: 'https://defix3.com',
        icons: ['https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/37784886'],
      ),
    );
```

Setup Sign Request Handling

```
 kadenaSignRequestHandler(String topic, dynamic parameters) async {
      // Handling Steps
      // 1. Parse the request, if there are any errors thrown while trying to parse
      // the client will automatically respond to the requester with a
      // JsonRpcError.invalidParams error
      final parsedResponse = parameters;

      // 2. Show a modal to the user with the signature info: Allow approval/rejection
      bool userApproved = await showDialog(
        // This is an example, you will have to make your own changes to make it work.
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Sign Transaction'),
            content: SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              height: 350,
              child: Text(parsedResponse.toString()),
            ),
            actions: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                child: const Text('Accept'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                child: const Text('Reject'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );

      // 3. Respond to the dApp based on user response
      if (userApproved) {
        return 'Signed!';
      } else {
        throw Errors.getSdkError(Errors.USER_REJECTED_SIGN);
      }
    }

    web3Wallet.registerRequestHandler(
      chainId: "1",
      method: 'kadena_sign',
      handler: kadenaSignRequestHandler,
    );
```

Setup Auth Request Handling

```
 web3Wallet.onAuthRequest.subscribe((AuthRequest? args) async {
      // This is where you would
      // 1. Store the information to be signed
      // 2. Display to the user that an auth request has been received

      // You can create the message to be signed in this manner
      String message = web3Wallet.formatAuthMessage(
        iss: "TEST_ISSUER_EIP191",
        cacaoPayload: CacaoRequestPayload.fromPayloadParams(
          args!.payloadParams,
        ),
      );

      // This is an example UI that can be presented to the user.
      // I expect you will need to make changes to this to fit your needs.
      bool userApproved = await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Approve Auth Request'),
            content: SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              height: 350,
              child: Text(message),
            ),
            actions: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                child: const Text('Accept'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                child: const Text('Reject'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );

      if (userApproved) {
        // In this example I use EthSigUtil, but you can use any library that can perform a personal eth sign.
        String sig = EthSigUtil.signPersonalMessage(
          message: Uint8List.fromList(message.codeUnits),
          privateKey: 'PRIVATE_KEY',
        );
        await web3Wallet.respondAuthRequest(
          id: args.id,
          iss: 'did:pkh:eip155:1:ETH_ADDRESS',
          signature: CacaoSignature(t: CacaoSignature.EIP191, s: sig),
        );
      } else {
        await web3Wallet.respondAuthRequest(
          id: args.id,
          iss: 'did:pkh:eip155:1:ETH_ADDRESS',
          error: WalletConnectError(
              code: 12001, message: 'User rejected the signature request'),
        );
      }
    });
```

//* Setup Response to a Session Proposal

```
late int id;
    web3Wallet.onSessionProposal.subscribe((SessionProposalEvent? args) async {
      // Handle UI updates using the args.params
      // Keep track of the args.id for the approval response
      id = args!.id;
    });

    final walletNamespaces = {
      'eip155': const Namespace(
        events: [],
        accounts: ['eip155:1:abc'],
        methods: ['eth_signTransaction'],
      ),
      'kadena': const Namespace(
        accounts: ['kadena:mainnet01:abc'],
        methods: ['kadena_sign_v1', 'kadena_quicksign_v1'],
        events: ['kadena_transaction_updated'],
      ),
    };
```

Pairing

```
await Permission.camera.request();
    String? barcode = await scanner.scan();
    log("scan: $barcode ✔️");
    if (barcode == null) return;

    final pairInfo = await web3Wallet.pair(uri: Uri.parse(barcode));
    log("$pairInfo 〰️");
```

Approve a Session Proposal

```
final approveResponse = await web3Wallet.approveSession(
        id: id,
        namespaces:
            walletNamespaces // This will have the accounts requested in params
        );

    log("$approveResponse ⭕");
```